# jquery: retrieve attr('id') of content that is generated via the ajax load function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Last year I made a simple to-do list using only php/mysql. I now would like to add jquery/ajax to make it more user friendly (mainly to get rid of the page refresh when adding or deleting a task).

The script to add a task works perfectly, and I load the task from the db using

```
$("#loadtaken").load("loadTaak.php");
```

loadTaak.php contains the following code:

```
session_start();
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'setup.php';

$q = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user = '$user[uid]' AND done = false ORDER BY created DESC";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) { ?>

            <ul class="items">
                <?php while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>


                <li><span class="item"><?php echo $items['name']; ?></span>
                <button id="<?php echo $items['todo_id']; ?>" class="done-button">Taak volbracht</button></li>
                <?php }
                ?>
            </ul>  <?php } 
             else {
                        echo "U hebt nog geen taken toegevoegd.";
                    }
```

I hoped I could grasp the id attribute of a task to mark it as done in the database, but that seems not to work. I tried the following:

```
$(".done-button").click(function(){


  var id =  $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);

});
```

Alas, computer says no :-(.

Comment: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: What does not work - does not work covers a lot of things - what exactly is not working - is the click working (looking at your code I don't think it should as you will need to use a delegated event), or is it just not alerting the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-initiate the javascript(after ajax content loaded) or load from the ajax content. Something like this,

```
session_start();
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'setup.php';

$q = "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user = '$user[uid]' AND done = false ORDER BY created DESC";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) { ?>

        <ul class="items">
            <?php while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>


            <li><span class="item"><?php echo $items['name']; ?></span>
            <button id="<?php echo $items['todo_id']; ?>" class="done-button">Taak volbracht</button></li>
<script>
$(".done-button").click(function(){

var id =  $(this).attr("data-id");
   alert(id);

});
```

Comment: Indeed, putting the jquery code in the loadTaak.php file instead of in the todolist.php file itself made it work!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain from the code snippet, but I think the problem is that your are binding the "click" event of the "done" buttons before they actually exit. The event handling code runs when the page loads (usually, this is what we can't see in your code) and attaches an event to any elements it finds which match the class name. Since you haven't loaded those elements (via ajax) yet, it can't attach an event handler to them.

One way to solve this is using delegated events, whereby you attach the event handler to an element higher up the DOM (it can be `document`, but better to be the nearest parent element which will be there when the page loads), and specify a selector to delegate the events to. It will then dynamically look for events with that selector whenever the handler is triggered, enabling it to find elements which weren't present when the handler was created:

```
$("#loadtaken").on("click", ".done-button", function(){
  var id =  $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

For more info please see http://api.jquery.com/on/ under the section "Direct and delegated events".

Comment: Just tried this approach without succes. So putting the jQuery script in the page that is loaded with the Ajax load function seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is good practice, but I made it work by putting the jquery code in the loadTaak.php file instead of in the todo-list page itself.